# Properties of set of points

Tags: geometry, statistics, data-analysis, discrete-geometry

Here is tinder fungus:
[image]
and it's pores:
[image]
I was wondering what can be said about this pattern.
Using Wolfram Mathematica we can get the following results.

Delaunay triangulation:
[image]
Voronoi diagram:
[image]

These patterns are not like packing circles. 
Something they remind, but I can not formulate (

Radial distribution function:
[image]
Last one causes a strong assumption that we are dealing with [short-range order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_range_order)
Is it so?
I was always interested in the low-discrepancy distributions.
The pattern of these pores looks very suitable.
I tried to calculate the discrepancy using [this article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/161438069.pdf).
But getting 0.25 for all known distributions :(
Is it possible to find a more detailed description of the calculation method for 2D discrepancy?
Additionally, I got histograms of the lengths of the edges and areas of triangles of Delaunay triangulation:
[image]
Can any interesting conclusions be drawn from this?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Have a look into partial symmetries. [Lawson's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/9810233167/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_i_kMCOEb0DHDCQ0) is a good place to start.